# IIS Request Filtering and Mime type for split zip file

Tags: security, iis

In IIS, how can you serve a split zip file such as those with extension using sequence (.z01, or .zip.001) without using * as a mimetype? This is to avoid serving other types as I understand * is a wild card for everything.

Similarly, is there a way to do the same with request filtering? Right now it looks like you can't specify wild cards. Just hard coded extension values.

Comment: i have the same problem, did you found any solution

Comment: I don't remember having found a solution except just hard coding values.

Comment: Couldn't find any solution on the web. I need to add a mime mapping for split zip files, the extensions are gonna be like .z01, .z02 etc. any ideas?

Comment: The solution was hard coding the extensions and setting a limit on the UI to only allow the files to be split to match the hard coded values.